# What's more accessible, text-indent: -9999px or just using an img with an alt tag?

Tags: html, css, seo

I've noticed a lot of articles popping up lately regarding accessibility and SEO best practices questioning the usage of the old CSS `text-indent: -9999px` trick, and I'm curious as to what is the best practice here.

An employee from Google says [it's not great](http://maileohye.com/html-text-indent-not-messing-up-your-rankings/) and `alt` tags on images are supposedly just fine for screen readers.  Is there any real truth behind this, and should I be changing up the way I'm handling some images on my sites?

Comment: See [Zeldman's article](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/) for possible performance drawbacks of large negative text indents.

Answer (score 5):

Image with an alt attribute.

The text-indent trick is all very well for screen reader users, but falls over for people who just have images turned off (or when images fail to load due to a network error (trying to use 3G on a moving train is *such* fun)).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the `alt` attribute is more accessible, unless the element whose text is indented is an header element (H1, H2, etc...) with a logo as its background.

In this case, I think that document structure is paramount, and it's important to use proper header text. This way, document structure is kept even when viewing the page with mosaic 1.0 :-)

Comment: Nothing stopping you from `<h2><img alt="..."></h2>`